# Extract integer part from String in python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a String like `gi|417072228|gb|JX515788.1|`. I need to extract the digit part `417072228` out of it using `python`. How can I split that part from the string? Should I use regular expression?

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: iterate over the characters in the string and use the ```isdigit``` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with `re.match`

```
>>> s = "gi|417072228|gb|JX515788.1|"
>>> [i for i in s.split('|') if re.match('^\d+$', i)]
['417072228']
>>> [i for i in s.split('|') if re.match('^\d+$', i)][0]
'417072228'
```

OR

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\||^)(\d+)(?:\||$)', s)
['417072228']
```

- `(?:\||^)` Matches the start of a line anchor or `|` symbol.
- `(\d+)` Captures one or more digit characters.
- `(?:\||$)` Matches `|` symbol or end of the line anchor.
- `re.findall` function will give the first preference to capturing group then to the matches. So here, it would print only the characters which are present inside the group index 1.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have delimiters in your input string already, which makes this easy to do with the methods built in to the string data type. No need for regular expressions.

```
for segment in s.split('|'):
    if segment.isdigit():
       # do your stuff with the number
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your input is a row from a CSV file, so if you just want the second column in each row you could do:

```
>>> row = 'gi|417072228|gb|JX515788.1|'
>>> row.split('|')[1]
'417072228'
```

Or to access all of the columns:

```
>>> columns = row.split('|')
>>> columns[0]
'gi'
>>> columns[1]
'417072228'
>>> columns[2]
'gb'
>>> columns[3]
'JX515788.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|(?<=\|))\d+(?=\||$)
```

You can simply use this with `re.findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/44

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:^|(?<=\|))\d+(?=\||$)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "gi|417072228|gb|JX515788.1|"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```